# Using virtual machine to create a cluster for big data?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, virtual-machine, virtualbox, bigdata

Is it possible to create a cluster with multiple nodes (4 or 5) on a virtual machine (VirtualBox), and to run Apache Spark to analyse the data within the nodes? The design of the cluster is to conform with the style of the HDFS, but NOT using HDFS. If it is possible, how would you distribute the data across the nodes? The idea of the project is to show how horizontal scaling works.

Comment: HDFS or any distributed or shared file system?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to create your own distributed file system and use Apache Spark on it?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want to do, the design of the file system is to 'mimic' the design of the HDFS.